# Is there a way to shrink a flexbox to it's minimum in an absolute positioned box

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm struggling with a flex-grid that's in a simple div-Container which is positioned absolutely.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. I want the whole box and grid to be compacted to its minimal possible size.
2. I don't want to set a width to the parent container as the content may vary in size.

Codesandbox example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-vaughan-hqpmz?file=/index.html

I added the Codesandbox example to this post to preserve it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <style type="text/css">
    .flexContainer {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    }
    
    .flexItem {}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
      ">
    <div class="flexContainer">
      <div class="flexItem">Line A:</div>
      <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>

      <div class="flexItem">Line B:</div>
      <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>

      <div class="flexItem">Line C:</div>
      <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>

      <div class="flexItem">Line D:</div>
      <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see there is a lot of unused space that looks very weird.
It looks like this is the space needed when there is no flex-basis and wrap.

Thanks for Tipps and Solutions.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use grid over flex for this problem.

Just add this css:

```
.flexContainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

And the result is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thats what I want. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .flexContainer {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        
        .flexItemDiv {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        
        .flexItem {
            margin: 5px 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        padding: 10px;
        
      ">
        <div class="flexContainer">
            <div class="flexItemDiv">
                <div class="flexItem">Line A:</div>
                <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItemDiv">
                <div class="flexItem">Line B:</div>
                <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItemDiv">
                <div class="flexItem">Line C:</div>
                <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>
            </div>

            <div class="flexItemDiv">
                <div class="flexItem">Line D:</div>
                <div class="flexItem">54,321.12 $</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```